# Getting Error im Django "Exception Value:name 'order_id' is not defined" whne query with a view to List Child records

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Getting Error im Django "Exception Value:name 'order_id' is not defined" whne query with a view to List Child records

I am making a custom View of a Cart that is Editable where I can still add/Update OrderItems. Problem is the View is showing all OrderItems from all Orders. No matter how I try to Filter the results I get an Error "name "xxxxxxx" is not Defined

The View works but list all Child Records

I cant format this in view

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  # used to send additional context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["title"] = 'Edit Sizing'
        context["savebtn"] = 'Update Sizing'
        context["delbtn"] = 'Delete Sizing'

        # data = cartData(request)
        # cartItems = data['cartItems']
        **items = OrderItem.objects.filter(orderitem__in=order_id)**
        # items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)

        orders = Order.objects.filter(orderitem__in=items)
        # items = OrderItem.objects.all()
        context = {'items': items, 'orders': orders}
        return context



Error in Browser

NameError at /sizing/1/edit

name 'order_id' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/sizing/1/edit
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'order_id' is not defined

Exception Location:     C:\Users\LS\source\repos\esstools17\esstools\store\views.py, line 58, in get_context_data
Python Executable:  C:\Users\LS\source\repos\esstools17\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.3
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\LS\\source\\repos\\esstools17\\esstools',
 'c:\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\LS\\source\\repos\\esstools17\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\LS\\source\\repos\\esstools17\\env\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 22 Jul 2021 23:41:03 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view 



Models.py

    class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
        date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        prepareded_by = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        date_modify = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        valid_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        acct_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        product = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        regions = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        salescon_num = models.CharField( max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        RFS_Num= models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Order, OrderItem, Product, ProdCategory, ProdVendor, AvProduct, Sla, Sizing, Album
from .serializers import OrderSerializer, SlaSerializer, AlbumSerializer
from .forms import OrderForm
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    View,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView
)
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from .filters import OrderFilter
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

from .utils import cookieCart, cartData, cartData2, guestOrder


class OrderListView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
    queryset = Order.objects.filter()
    template_name = 'store/sizing.html'
    paginate_by = 10


def sizer(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/sizer.html', context)


class OrderUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):  # updateview class to edit sizing, mixin used to display message
    model = Order  # setting 'Sizing' model as model
    form_class = OrderForm  # setting 'SizingForm' form as form
    template_name = "store/edit_sizing.html"  # 'edit_sizing.html' used as the template
    success_url = '/sizing'  # redirects to 'sizing' page in the url after submitting the form
    success_message = "Sizing has been updated successfully"  # displays message when form is submitted

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  # used to send additional context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["title"] = 'Edit Sizing'
        context["savebtn"] = 'Update Sizing'
        context["delbtn"] = 'Delete Sizing'

        # data = cartData(request)
        # cartItems = data['cartItems']
        items = OrderItem.objects.filter(orderitem__in=order_id)
        # items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)

        orders = Order.objects.filter(orderitem__in=items)
        # items = OrderItem.objects.all()
        context = {'items': items, 'orders': orders}
        return context




class OrderDeleteView(View):  # view class to delete sizing
    template_name = "delete_sizing.html"  # 'delete_sizing.html' used as the template
    success_message = "Sizing has been deleted successfully"  # displays message when form is submitted

    def get(self, request, pk):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'object': order})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
        order.is_deleted = True
        order.save()
        messages.success(request, self.success_message)
        return redirect('sizing')


# class OrderItemListView(generic.ListView):
#     model = OrderItem
#     context_object_name = 'orderitem_list'   # your own name for the list as a template variable
#     queryset = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id__icontains='war')[:5] # Get 5 books containing the title war
#     template_name = 'store/edit_sizing.html'  # Specify your own template name/location


def store(request):

    #form = OrderForm()
    #if request.method == 'Post':

    #   form = OrderForm(request.Post)
    #   if form.is_valid():
    #       form.save()


    #context = {'form':form}
    
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

##Added as a updated feature
def dashboard(request):

    #form = OrderForm()
    #if request.method == 'Post':
    #   form = OrderForm(request.Post)
    #   if form.is_valid():
    #       form.save()
    #context = {'form':form}

    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/dashboard.html', context)


def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def sizer(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/sizer.html', context)

def createsizerview(request):
    # dictionary for initial data with 
    # field names as keys
    context ={}
  
    # add the dictionary during initialization
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
          
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "store/createsizerview.html", context)

class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('transaction_id')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

def checkout(request):
    data = cartData(request)
    
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)

def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
        order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        order=order,
        address=data['shipping']['address'],
        city=data['shipping']['city'],
        state=data['shipping']['state'],
        zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
        )

    return JsonResponse('Payment submitted..', safe=False)

#******  DataTables Views  *******

class SlaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sla.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SlaSerializer

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            sla = query_sla_by_args(**request.query_params)
            serializer = SlasSerializer(sla['items'], many=True)
            result = dict()
            result['data'] = serializer.data
            result['draw'] = sla['draw']
            result['recordsTotal'] = sla['total']
            result['recordsFiltered'] = sla['count']
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, template_name=None, content_type=None)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)
```

Comment: I get the Same Error no matter what Value I add to...., 

items = OrderItem.objects.filter(orderitem__in=order_id)

Comment: Code below works but returns all OrderItems where I only want the OrderItems associated with the "Order"...., 

items = OrderItem.objects.all()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't defined an `order_id` variable. Or did I not see it.

```
items = OrderItem.objects.filter(orderitem__in=order_id)
```

Comment: I made several Changes but am still not getting it...., the error just Changes to include what ever Field or variable I add. I am sure it is my misunderstanding



  # data = cartData(request)
  # cartItems = data['cartItems']
  **order_id = Order.id**
  **items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=order_id)**
  # items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)

  orders = Order.objects.filter(orderitem__in=items)
  # items = OrderItem.objects.all()
  context = {'items': items, 'orders': orders}
  return context

Comment: TypeError at /sizing/1/edit

Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002761FD5CA60>.

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8081/sizing/1/edit
Django Version:  3.2.4
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

**Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002761FD5CA60>.**

Comment: So where does this Order come from? Can you check the ```Order``` and ```Order.id``` values with the print function? I would appreciate it if you could share the output here.